# Is there a way to simply listen for changes to an object, not what changes were made?

Tags: java, javafx, observable, fxml, changelistener

#### Summary

I have an object of type "MyClass" called "myClassInstance" which has an ArrayList of objects. All contained objects implement the Serializable interface and will be written to file.

I need to be able to know when this object has changed in any way to update a JavaFX ListView whenever there are any changes to the object (Including any objects it contains).

Essentially any time "myClassInstance.hashCode" would return a different number, I want to be able to call an update method to update ui elements.

#### Background

I have looked for a solution to this problem and found many pages which seem to have solutions, however I cant help but think these solutions which all seem to require a significant rewrite of the model classes I have all are entirely too complex for the problem I have.

Almost all seem to refer to Property Change Listeners, to know about changes to specific Properties/fields, but I do not need anything this specific. I simply need to know whether or not the object "myClassInstance" has been changed. Has the value returned by "myClassInstance.hashCode" changed. Not if any of the properties have changed, or if the properties of the objects it contains changed but if anything in "myClassInstance" has changed.

#### Relevant code snippets

Class that needs to be observed:

```
public class myClass implements Serializable {
private ArrayList<SpecificObjectType> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();

public myClass () {
newSpecificObjectType(); //creates default specific object type
}

// Classes related to changing, retrieving or deleting elements of myObjects
}
```

FXMLMainDocument.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" "package.FXMLMainController">
   <center>
      <ListView fx:id="listViewObjects" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
   <top>
      <Button fx:id="editButton" onAction="#handleEditAction" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

FXMLEditDocument.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="package.FXMLEditController">
   <center>
      <TextField fx:id="edit" onAction="#handleNameTextField"  promptText="This Edits The Name of One of the Objects in MyClass's ArrayList" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

FXMLMainController:

```
@FXML
private ListView listViewObjects;

private MyClass myClassInstance;
private ObservableList<String> obsObjects;
```

...

```
public void update() {
        this.obsObjects.setAll(myClassInstance.getMyObjectNames());
    }

@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        this.myClassInstance = new MyClass();
        obsObjects = FXCollections.observableArrayList(myClassInstance.getMyObjectNames());
        this.listViewObjects.setItems(obsObjects);
        update();
    }
```

#### Edit:

I have decided to try the Observable, Observer route. The secondary controller is now observable and the primary an observer. When certain actions are triggered in the secondary, the primary updates. This works, although Im not fully certain it can do everything I want it to. Il probably have a sit on this after which I'll Label the relevant answer.

Comment: Does the object provide a way to listen to changes? If not, you're out of luck and have to rely on the code modifying the object for notification. Also note that equality of 2 objects implies the same hash code (assuming a correct implementation); This does not mean that 2 objects that aren't equal cannot share the same hash code...

Comment: @fabian, I've current made MyClass extend Observable and made the Controller an observer, however its the update part that still has me confused or perhaps just doesnt do what I was hoping it would do.

It seems I still have to find a way to get MyClass to run setChange and notifyObservers with every change, which is essentially the entire challenge.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are after and how [the answer by Zephyr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55682285/203657) doesn't work for you.

Comment: @kleopatra, There isnt really a complete example as Im trying to figure out how it should work right now. I have made some example FXML files to go along with the snippets I've added so far and will continue to add to it to try to make it complete.

As for solutions posted, Ive come to the conclusion that Matts will work but not in the way I wanted it to. I want MyClassInstance to observed for any changes, but this method will allow me to trigger an update whenever the secondary controller which edits it does. Zephyrs solution involves changing all of the fields of all of the classes.

Comment: "Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them." @kleo

The names of these in practice are all different. I picked these names to explain what function these parts have in the program without needing to explain what the program does outside of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's `Observables`. The object you want to monitor should extend `Observable`, and the monitoring class should implement `Observer`.

See the documentation for [`Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) and [`Observer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html).

Comment: So I'm trying to do this right now, and well, unless Im missing something, this seems to require about as much change. Am I missing something or do I have to figure out a way to always have every change manually trigger the setChange/notify method?

Comment: _Note: The `java.util.Observable` and `java.util.Observer` classes were deprecated in Java 9._

Answer (score 1):

Your class doesn't appear to have any `public` fields, correct? Could you not simply add a `BooleanProperty` to the class and update it from any setters in the class?

For instance:

```
private BooleanProperty hasChanged = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
```

Then in any of your setters, update that property:

```
public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.hasChanged.set(true);
}
```

Comment: This needs to happen when any of the objects in the array have their attributes changed as well. Its not an *elegant* design, as the data members of the objects inside are allowed to escape, but what that means is that the setters in MyClass do not cover all of the changes that may occur in the objects it holds.